# Stop a tkinter function that has a "return"

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

My code is currently graphing and writing text files of the graph data.  I want it to stop doing this.  Instead of stopping, it just starts the process over.  I've tried several things (stopping **get_data** function, stopping **update_graph** function, having a **separate stop** function).  What am I missing?

```
def on_click(self):

    if self.ani is None:
        # animation is not running; start it
        return self.start()

def start(self):
    self.points = int(tkvar.get()) + 1
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
        self.fig,
        self.update_graph,
        frames=self.points,
        interval=int(self.interval.get()),
        repeat=True)
    self.running = True
    self.btn.config(text='Started')
    self.ani._start()
    print('started animation')

def get_data(self, i):
    files = tkvar.get()
    global after_id
    global filenumber
    global tkvars
    filenumber = int(files)

    inttime = tkvars.get()
    thetime = inttime.encode()
    ser.write(thetime)
    f = open("Serial" + str(i) + ".txt", 'w+')#encoding='utf-8')              
    #f = open("serial%d.txt") % (i)
    data=ser.readline() #read the defined serial import
    f.write(str(data)) #place data into the text file
    f.close() #close the text file

    lines = open("Serial" + str(i) + ".txt", 'r+')#, encoding='utf-8')  #open that same text file (reading priviledges)

    read_serial=lines.readline() #read the text file
    global mylist
    mylist = [int(x) for x in read_serial.split(',') if x.strip().isdigit()] #make the read data an interger and strip it of any data that is not a number (comma, ending/beginning letters)
    global x
    x = np.linspace(340, 850, num=len(mylist)) #creation of x axis
    ax1.clear()
    lines.close() #close the text file
    ax1.plot(x, mylist)
    plt.ylim([0, 1000])
    print(filenumber)
    print(i)
    return i
    if True:
        self.after_id = self.after(1, self.get_data, i+1)



def update_graph(self, i):
    self.get_data(i)
    global mylist
    global x
    global filenumber
    self.line.set_data(x, mylist)#(self.get_data()) # update graph
    if i >= self.points + 1:
        #root.update()
        self.btn.config(text='Start')
        self.stop()
        self.running = False
        self.ani = None
    return self.line,

def stop(self):
    self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

Comment: Can you please produce a [mcve] of the issue. I.e. when I copy and paste the code and run it I would need to be able to see the issue.

Comment: I can paste/attach all the python code (I am currently at school, the Raspberry Pi is at home?)  Do you need text files of the data as well?

Comment: The values presented under "text" file example range usually from 100 to 1000.

Comment: That looks like way too much code. Do you really need all that code to illustrate the problem? Please read how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the only problem, but it is certainly part of the problem. This code does not do what you think it does:

```
self.after(0, self.get_data(i+1))
```

The above is identical to the following:

```
result = self.get_data(i+1)
self.after(0, result)
```

... which for all intents and purposes the same as this:

```
result = self.get_data(i+1)
result()
```

When you call `after`, you must give it a *callable*. Also, you shouldn't give a value of zero because under some conditions you will prevent the event loop from being able to process events such as requests to refresh the display. You should at the very least give a value of 1, and preferably something a bit bigger.

The proper way to use `after` to call a function with an argument is like this:

```
self.after(1, self.get_data, i+1)
```

I presume you also intended to be able to cancel the call to `self.get_data`, so you need to do this:

```
self.after_id = self.after(1, self.get_data, i+1)
```

... and then modify `stop` to be this:

```
def stop(self):
    self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

Comment: I will give this a try.  Sorry for the messy, beginner code.  I've just encounter so many issues, I just slap something down.  And, if it seems to work I go with it.  I wish I could have started learning python with a simpler project.  :/  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @keakins13: _"I just slap something down. And, if it seems to work I go with it."_ - that's not a very good strategy. You need to be methodical, and start small and work your way up.  Your code appears to have many issues, and trying to solve them all at once will be very difficult even for an experienced programmer.

Comment: So, it appears (and I should have known this) that it was never going through the if True statement.  meaning, the self.after was never touched.  When I get rid of the statement and put it (with your edits) before return i, it doesn't show on the graph and keeps looping still (very slowly).  Edits to code coming (with your recommendations).

Comment: You have a very good point.  I wish I could go back and start a bit more slowly.  But I was given a (in my opinion) pretty advanced project and a deadline.... I have very little programming experience. I'm REALLY sorry for the sloppy code.... :/